# Align button in list-group-item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fit in a button in a list-group-item, but it just looks horrible (buttons exceed the height of the list-group-item):
[image]

```
<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound1
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form><span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:58</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound2
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form><span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:15</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound3
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form><span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:07</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

How would I implement this correctly?

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant CSS?

Comment: I don't have any additional CSS, this is just plain bootstrap. The only CSS involved is the margin for the badge, and this is inlined atm

Comment: You just need `margin-left` of bootstrap. Change button claas to this : `<button class="btn btn-md btn-default ml-3" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>`

Comment: Sadly, even without the form around it, ml-3 does nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7dwaxo72/

```css
form {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound1
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
              <span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:58</span>
              <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound2
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
                <span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:15</span>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Sound3
            <form class="form-inline pull-right vertical-align">
              <span class="badge" style="margin-right: 10px;">0:07</span>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Hope this will help. I've changed the `HTML` structure a bit.